# kivy multiple boxlayout in scrollview

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Below is the content of kivy file (.kv) i am trying to create a scrollview which will have multiple box layout ( like one in ecommerce layout list view ) but not sure whats wrong here.

```
<gridlay>:
    #size_hint: 1, None
    #size: 1000, 1000
    #pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'top': 1}
    do_scroll_x: False

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: None
        #height: self.minimum_height
        #height: 1
        orientation:"vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            Button:
                text:"M1"
                size_hint: .7,.3
            Button:
                text:"M2"
                size_hint: .7,.2
            Button:
                text:"m3"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            Button:
                text:"M1"
                size_hint: .7,.3
            Button:
                text:"M2"
                size_hint: .7,.2
            Button:
                text:"m3"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            Button:
                text:"M1"
                size_hint: .7,.3
            Button:
                text:"M2"
                size_hint: .7,.2
            Button:
                text:"m3"
<ScrollButton@Button>
    size_hint: None,None
    #size_hint: 900, 40
```

[image]

Comment: What does your desired result look like?

Comment: it should look like list view of some ecommerce app like rectangular boxone at the top of other and each box will have three sub boxes

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. A painted picture of the desired result would help me understand.